# How to extract string information from these two strings?

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a single regular expression code to extract the string from these two strings:

```
string1 = '@HISEQ:625:HC2T5BCXY:1:1101:1177:2101'
string2 = '@SRR7216015.1 HISEQ:630:HC2VKBCXY:1:1101:1177:2073/1'
```

I want to extract the string right after the @ until it hit the end or a space to get

```
HISEQ:625:HC2T5BCXY:1:1101:1177:2101 from string1
```

or

```
SRR7216015.1 from string2
```

So, how to do it. I've tested a bunch of the regular expression code but couldn't do it.

Below is the code I tried:

```
string1 = '@HISEQ:625:HC2T5BCXY:1:1101:1177:2101'
string2 = '@SRR7216015.1 HISEQ:630:HC2VKBCXY:1:1101:1177:2073/1'
pattern1 = re.compile(r'@(\w*.*:*\d*:*\w*:*\d*:*\d*[$|\s])')
print(pattern1.search(string1).group(1))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are open to other options and your string always have @ in beginning then this can be easily achieved with `split` method.

Comment: how to do it with split?

Comment: Just use this `string1[1:].split(" ")[0]`

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried ?

Comment: @m0dknight This will not work as desired if there is a space in the string it will give wrong output

Comment: Have you tried `"@\S+"` ?

Comment: @Eternal It does works with space. Without any issue.  `string1.split('@')[-1]`

Comment: @m0dknight well, your comment is somehow deleted. Post it again so we can try and see.

Comment: @Eternal I read the requirement wrong. I thought it's till the end. It's till end or space. Yes, it won't work in that case.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks so much for your answers, string1[1:].split(" ")[0]  works, this help my understanding of the split() method a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
@(\S+)
```

and take the first group. Lookarounds or alternations - as suggested in other answers - are expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually works and improved my understanding of \S

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex for that:

```
(?<=@).*?(?= |$)
```

Use lookarounds. `(?<=@)` checks for an @ signt before, `(?= |$)` matches an spaces or end of string. `.*` mathes everything between

https://regex101.com/r/p7kI2O/1

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I tested but it gave me an error.

Comment: What exact errodid you receivedr?

Comment: Hi, I just researched your method a little bit and found it actually work and it doesn't give the result in the form of a group, but a matched object that contain the information that I want